# TensorFlow / Keras: What is stateful = True in LSTM layers?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, lstm, rnn, gru

Could you elaborate on this argument? I found [the brief explanation from the docs](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/LSTM?version=stable) unsatisfying:

> stateful: Boolean (default False). If True, the last state for each sample at index i in a batch will be used as initial state for the sample of index i in the following batch.

Also, when `stateful = True` is to be chosen? What are practical cases of its use?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53010965/keras-lstm-difference-stateless-and-stateful) discussion might help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This flag is used to have truncated back-propagation through time: the gradient is propagated through the hidden states of the LSTM across the time dimension in the batch and then, in the next batch, the last hidden states are used as input states for the LSTM.

This allows the LSTM to use longer context at training time while constraining the number of steps back for the gradient computation.

I know of two scenarios where this is common:

- Language modeling (LM).
- Time series modeling.

The training set is a list of sequences, potentially coming from a few documents (LM) or complete time series. During data preparation, the batches are created so that each sequence in a batch is the continuation of the sequence at the same position in the previous batch. This allows having document-level/long time series context when computing predictions.

In these cases, your data is longer than the sequence length dimension in the batch. This may be due to constraints in the available GPU memory (therefore limiting the maximum batch size) or by design due to any other reasons.

**Update**: Note that the `stateful` flag affects both training and inference time. If you disable it, you must ensure that at inference time each prediction gets the previous hidden state. For this, you can either create a new model with `stateful=True` and copy the parameters from the trained model with `model.set_weights()` or pass it *manually*. Due to this inconvenience, some people simply set `stateful = True` always and force the model not use the stored hidden state during training by invoking `model.reset_states()`.

Comment: I am training a text generator RNN. Since the model is too large for my current hardware, I am sampling input sequences from the corpus instead of making it read it all batch by batch. Does it make sense to set `stateful = True` for my LSTM layers, knowing that input sequences are smapled randomly? Or does `stateful = True` work only if I feed text sequences *sequentially*, i.e. in the same order of the original text ?

Comment: Using `stateful=True` does not make much sense in your case, because you are not providing batches that maintain the sequence continuity.

Comment: Do you think I should feed batches with textual continuity and set `stateful=True` ? Can this improve my training or it doesn't make a difference?

Comment: In LM it normally helps a bit, but it really depends on the data, i.e. whether having a long context actually provides a stronger predictive signal than just local context.

Comment: I tried to repeat the [text generation code from TF website](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/text/text_generation). Here too input sequences are sampled randomly from the whole corpus. Still, if I drop `stateful = True` the quality of generated text decreases A LOT. What do you think?

Comment: In that example, the problem is that the code generating text (inference time) relies on the fact that `stateful = True` to pass the previous hidden state to the computation of the next prediction. When you made `stateful = False`, you invalidated such an assumption. Therefore, all predictions are generated with an input hidden state of `0`, effectively making the predictions unconditional from the previous text.

Comment: Also note that, while the GRU is created with `stateful = True`, the training does not use the stored hidden because `model.reset_states()` is invoked just before every training iteration.

Comment: I updated my answer with a remark on this `stateful = True` + `model.reset_states()` idiom.

Comment: upvoted for the last paragraph ("Update"). It is really an accurate use-case of stateful LSTMs.